# How to estimate Inference time from average forward pass time in caffe?

Tags: benchmarking, caffe, conv-neural-network

I use this command to benchmark my ConvNet in caffe:

```
./build/tools/caffe time -model models/own_xx/deploy.prototxt -weights examples/RSR_50k_all_1k_db/snapshot_iter_10000.caffemodel -gpu=0
```

It runs fine and generates output which ends with:

```
I0426 16:08:19.345427 15441 caffe.cpp:377] Average Forward pass: 13.5549 ms.
I0426 16:08:19.345484 15441 caffe.cpp:379] Average Backward pass: 10.7661 ms.
I0426 16:08:19.345527 15441 caffe.cpp:381] Average Forward-Backward: 25.2922 ms.
I0426 16:08:19.345579 15441 caffe.cpp:383] Total Time: 1264.61 ms.
I0426 16:08:19.345628 15441 caffe.cpp:384] *** Benchmark ends ***
```

In some tutorials I have seen the guy somehow simply infer the classification time from Average Forward pass. However, I can not find any formula or material which explain how to do this. Is there actually some link between the two entites? Which other factors e.g. number of iterations, and batch size are involved? My goal is to accurately predict classification time of my ConvNet on the GPU.

UPDATE: To not appear completely ignorant I will add here that I have a basic idea that forward pass is the time taken by an input to generate a relative output so it can be called the inference time too. However, what I am interested in is knowing if that is true irrespective of batch size and iterations? I tried but during benchmarking, caffe does not offer any 'batch' options.

Comment: does your deploy.prototxt has an input layer? look at the input size defined in the prototxt this will tell you what batch size caffe used for timing

Comment: @Shai Yes I am sure about the batch size as I wrote the network myself. What I can't figure out is how it is related to forward passes and classification time of image. Finding classification time of an image is my goal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The average forward pass time is the time it takes to propagate one batch of inputs from the input ("data") layer to the output layer. The batch size specified in your `models/own_xx/deploy.prototxt` file will determine how many images are processed per batch.

For instance, if I run the default command that comes with Caffe:

```
build/tools/caffe time --model=models/bvlc_alexnet/deploy.prototxt --gpu=0
```

I get the following output

```
...
I0426 13:07:32.701490 30417 layer_factory.hpp:77] Creating layer data
I0426 13:07:32.701513 30417 net.cpp:91] Creating Layer data
I0426 13:07:32.701529 30417 net.cpp:399] data -> data
I0426 13:07:32.709048 30417 net.cpp:141] Setting up data
I0426 13:07:32.709079 30417 net.cpp:148] Top shape: 10 3 227 227 (1545870)
I0426 13:07:32.709084 30417 net.cpp:156] Memory required for data: 6183480
...
I0426 13:07:34.390281 30417 caffe.cpp:377] Average Forward pass: 16.7818 ms.
I0426 13:07:34.390290 30417 caffe.cpp:379] Average Backward pass: 12.923 ms.
I0426 13:07:34.390296 30417 caffe.cpp:381] Average Forward-Backward: 29.7969 ms.
```

The following line:

```
I0426 13:07:32.709079 30417 net.cpp:148] Top shape: 10 3 227 227 (1545870)
```

is super important. It says that your input layer is 10x3x227x227-dimensional. In this case, the batch size is 10 images, each of size 3x227x227 (the 3 refers to each of the rgb channels in an image).

So effectively, it took 1.67818 ms/image to do a forward pass or inference time per image.

**Changing the batch size**

If you want to change the batch size, look at your .prototxt file. The
`models/bvlc_alexnet/deploy.prototxt` file that comes with Caffe looks like the following:

```
name: "AlexNet"
layer {
  name: "data"
  type: "Input"
  top: "data"
  input_param { shape: { dim: 10 dim: 3 dim: 227 dim: 227 } }
}
layer { ...
```

Simply change dim: 10 into some other value (say to '100' to specify a batch size of 100 images per forward pass).

Comment: Thank you for the clear and detailed explanation. I understand it properly now. However, I have one follow up question. Using this method I tested with various batch sizes to get classification times. My results are:
`CT: 0.098ms with Batchsize of 6000
CT: 0.11ms with Batchsize of 1000
CT: 0.18ms with Batchsize of 100
CT: 1.07ms with Batchsize of 10
CT: 7.68ms with Batchsize of 1`
I want to know why the inference times also change with batch size. I am using NVIDIA TX1 for these tests.

Comment: I can guess:
a. I am under-utilizing GPU's ability with batch sizes of 1 and 10.
b. For larger batch sizes (100,1000,6000) the time is approx 0.1ms.
c. This also shows that I can fully utilize my GPU for a high memory cost or save memory and keep the GPU under-utilized.
Am I correct in making these assumptions. Please do add what I have missed.

Comment: I also want to add that if I increase batchsize more than 7000. The process is killed automatically which I guess is due to not sufficient memory.

Comment: Your intuition on batch size and GPU utilization is correct; we need to have enough work on the GPU (large batch sizes) to make good use of all of its resources.

A simple analogy is a baker baking cookies in an oven. While we can bake 100 cookies one at a time, this is foolish considering our oven can bake all 100 in one batch. The oven has enough power to bake all 100 instead of baking a cookie 100 times.

And yep, for sufficiently large batch sizes, the GPU can run out of memory. In our baking analogy, it's like stuffing the oven with a million cookies ... It just doesn't fit.

Comment: Thanks you for the detailed and nice explanation!

Comment: hai @CarlodelMundo and Qazi. Apologize for jumping to your discussion. I do the same thing but surprisingly got unexpected result. When using 10 batch size with GPU I get the `Total Time: 12881.4 ms`. However, when I changed the batch size to 50 I got a longer time as `Total Time: 58539.2 ms.`. Or was this expected? Thanks

Comment: You increased the amount of work to be done by 5x and executed time increased by a factor of 5x. Sounds OK to me.